# Facebook get recent post with particular HashTag via API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

How to get recent public post with particular hashtag from Facebook ? Is it supported by Facebook ?

I do not see any related endpoint here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4

Answer (score 0):

No, since Graph API v2.0 the search for public posts is no longer possible.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> Public Post search is no longer available. (`/search?type=post&q=foobar`)